# Alignment of bullets within the itemize environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, itemize

I have a question regarding the alignment of bullets within the itemize example, here a short example. Basically I have an \item with an inserted table and I want the bullet to be at the top of the table[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item  \begin{tabular}{c p{11.4cm}} 04.2014 - 05.2014: & teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeessssssssssssssssssssstttttttttttttttttttttt
 pppppppppphhhhhhhhhhaaaaaaaaaasssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeee \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\begin{tabular}[t]` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Typing

```
\begin{itemize}
\item  \begin{tabular}[t]{c p{11.4cm}} 04.2014 - 05.2014: & teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeessssssssssssssssssssstttttttttttttttttttttt
 pppppppppphhhhhhhhhhaaaaaaaaaasssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeee \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
```

will solve the issue, but my impression is that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Try this one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{cvitemize}
 {\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\citemwd,labelwidth=\citemwd,labelsep=0pt]}
 {\end{itemize}}

\newlength{\citemwd}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\citemwd}{\textbullet\ 00.0000--00.0000:\ }%
}

\newcommand{\citem}[1]{%
  \item[\textbullet\ #1:\ ]%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{cvitemize}
\citem{04.2014--05.2014} \lipsum*[3]
\end{cvitemize}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional argument to `tabular` for specifying the vertical position.  `t` specifies that the baseline of the top row should align with surrounding text.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}[t]{c p{11.4cm}} 04.2014 - 05.2014: & teee
    eeeeeee eeeeeeee essssss ssssssss ssssssst ttttttt ttttttttt ttttt
    pp pppp pppphhh hhhhhh haaaaa aaaaas ssssss ssseee eeeeee
    eeee \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

With no option the `tabular` is vertically centered with respect to the text around. With the `b` option the baseline of the last row of the tabular is used; note in a `p` column that will be the baseline of the line of that entry so in your case that will produced the same alignment that you asked for:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{tabular}[t]{c p{5cm}} 04.2014 - 05.2014: & teee
    eeeeeee eeeeeeee essssss ssssssss ssssssst ttttttt ttttttttt ttttt
    pp pppp pppphhh hhhhhh haaaaa aaaaas ssssss ssseee eeeeee
    eeee \end{tabular}
\item \begin{tabular}{c p{5cm}} 04.2014 - 05.2014: & teee
    eeeeeee eeeeeeee essssss ssssssss ssssssst ttttttt ttttttttt ttttt
    pp pppp pppphhh hhhhhh haaaaa aaaaas ssssss ssseee eeeeee
    eeee \end{tabular}
\item \begin{tabular}[b]{c p{5cm}} 04.2014 - 05.2014: & teee
    eeeeeee eeeeeeee essssss ssssssss ssssssst ttttttt ttttttttt ttttt
    pp pppp pppphhh hhhhhh haaaaa aaaaas ssssss ssseee eeeeee
    eeee \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `listliketab`package: a tabular environment in which the first column can emulate any list environment:

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, textwidth = 15cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{listliketab}
    \newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet}
     \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dic- tum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

    \storestyleof{itemize}
    \begin{listliketab}
     \begin{tabular}{Lc p{8cm}}
    \tabitem  & 04.2014 - 05.2014: & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dic- tum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
     \end{tabular}
     \end{listliketab}

     \end{document}
```

[image]